# css-only table manipulation

Tags: css, html-table

I have a need to manipulate the layout of a table differently depending on certain conditions. I am not able to alter the HTML (with the exception of adding CSS class names) and I cannot use any Javascript. I must try and do everything using CSS only.

I have done almost everything except for one layout.

I need to turn a regular table row, such as the following...

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| CELL 1 | CELL 2 | CELL 3 | CELL 4 | CELL 5 | CELL 6 | CELL 7 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

... into a multiple rowed table, with the 2nd and further rows containing only one 100% width cell

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| CELL 1 | CELL 2 | CELL 3 | CELL 4 |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|               CELL 5              |
+-----------------------------------+
|               CELL 6              |
+-----------------------------------+
|               CELL 7              |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What is the HTML markup, and exactly how should it be styled? In particular, what width should the table have? There is nothing corresponding to `colspan` in CSS, so you would need a fake table (perhaps using table layout for the first four cells but setting `display: block` on other cells). The details depend on the overall formatting you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible, and with pure CSS:

```
tr {
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
}
td {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
td:nth-child(-n+4) {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
```

Also, check this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/Cz58f/)

Comment: That is perfect.  Never considered making the row a block element.  Thanks for your help.